# How can I mount a toilet bowl on a raised flange?

Tags: plumbing

I removed this toilet after it was wobbling and then stripped back the wax ring to find that there’s this hard concrete pad that sticks up from the tile about 1 inch. I’m not sure what wax ring I can use on this type of flange. I don’t want this one that I have on now to raise the toilet up so much that I have to shim it from the floor.

Does anyone know how I can solve this problem? The house is very old (from early 1900s). I don’t have access below this.

[image: flange without top]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us what it looks like without your new addition on top covering everything?

Comment: Are you sure that is concrete and not a cast iron flange?  Age of the house might help, an older house more likely to use cast iron pipe.

Comment: @brhans yep here you go

Comment: @crip659 , I now believe it to be cast iron , the house is very old from early 1900s

Comment: @isherwood I don’t have access below this

Comment: The second pic is helpful, but a 3rd from the "cup angle" (with that red cup of... goop in the background) but without the flange on top would be even better.

Answer (score 4):

You either have a thick cast iron flange or a raised flange from when there was a full mortar bed under tile at some point. It's a challenging situation for sure, which I've helped deal with before but with unsatisfactory results. You have two options for a good outcome:

- Replace the flange. This obviously would involve opening the floor. Some tile repair would probably be required.
- Raise the floor. You could install a small rectangular platform to bring the toilet resting surface to where it should be. This might be a simple as a second layer of tile with a bullnose edge.

Bonus option: Find a manufacturer who makes a toilet with a more recessed drain surface. This is a fairly common problem when old floors are replaced, so maybe there's one to be had.

Comment: Option 2b: the platform can be cut from a white composite board using the toilet as a template, essentially one huge shim.  Cut slightly smaller than the toilet so it supports the edge but will be hidden by caulk.  Don't start with an ADA toilet so it won't be too high.

Comment: I like the idea, but not the notion that you'd cover the entire edge with caulk. That doesn't sound nice. I'd have a tiny bead at the floor and one at the toilet. If undersized, as you suggest, this would look good.